# audio routing on windows phone?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, audio, routes, call

I'm making an app that should let me call someone and have him listening to sounds I recorded. When I play the sounds on my own, it goes out of the built-in speaker, and when I use it while on the phone, the sounds are not played at all!

Or I'd like to be able to make my sounds follow the same path as my voice does while talking to someone. What could I do? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with the current version of the Windows Phone SDK. Unless you plan on [creating your own VoIP app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206983%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for Windows Phone 8 (sample available [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/ChatterBox-VoIP-sample-app-b1e63b8b)).

Comment: Ouch, that hurts! But let's suppose I go through creating a VoIP app, I could really do what I want? Thank you for your time, anyway

Comment: Direct audio stream manipulation is what you're looking for, and unless you have that done server-side, there is no way to push it to a call.

Comment: Ok, I'm browsing the msdn documenttation...I mark you as the answer, anyway, but if you know some better tutorials on this subject, please let me know. Thanks!!

Comment: Well, looks like I can't find anything relevant....If someone can help, please do so.